# Relative Movements Agreement on Object speed

Tags: energy, relativity, relative-motion

I am confused about Relative Motion.Lets suppose we have one train and two observer.One of them inside the train and the other one is outside.Lets think the outside observer see the train moves a constant velocity v.The observer in the train will be think it is not moving cause of Galileo Principle.The outside observer will think kinetic energy will be $mv^2/2$ but the inside observer cant say anything (or will say zero cause he will think its not moving). Now lets think a special situation which two observer can agree the speed.(I know its not possible but lets think that's possible). In this case Can two observers agree on kinetic energy of train(In this case again its violates Galileo principle cause the observer in the train know its moving but he cant proof)here I am started to confused.What can be solution Can they agree on kinetic energy cause of no proof of movement ?

Comment: The kinetic energy is not unique. That is, not all observer will measure it to have the same value. This is not a problem for the conservation of energy, because the conservation rule presupposes that the before and after measurements are made in the same frame of reference.

Answer (score -1):

First of all Galilean Transformation laws are not valid in most cases. For the moving reference frames the special theory of relativity is more suitable. In fact it is the most suitable one given the experimental data. In special relativity one defines a so-called energy-momentum four vector, whose magnitude every observer in an inertial reference frame agrees upon.

Comment: Meh. This is strictly true but not helpful unless the OP is more advanced that the question suggests. For the purposes of day-to-day understanding the the Galilean transformation is fine and a lot less confusing than the Lorentz transformation.

Comment: So they can agree ? Is there any importance that you can proof you can move or not move

Comment: @dmckee Though it is true and I also know that OP doesn't have the knowledge of SR, I didn't know how else to answer since Galilean transformations can lead to paradoxes like that. I could also say that you set the kinetic energy to be zero for an object that is not moving in your reference frame, which I find to be really vague. eg. I am now going around the sun and the milky way but I don't say that my car has a kinetic energy of such and such joules, as far as the effects of these motions is not present.

Comment: @ArmanÇam Yes of course it is important that you can *prove* (actually it is somewhat postulated) you cannot tell if you are moving or not as long as you don't look out the window. The very principles of SR are based on this fact.

Comment: There is no "paradox" here. Not in the Galilean transformations nor in the Lorentz transformations. Kinetic energy is not a invariant quantity in either case, and observers in different frames will get different values for both theories.

Comment: @dmckee I admit paradox was a poor choice of word.

Comment: But I made a special case which they can agree of speed

Comment: How can they agree upon the speed of the train if one is on the train and has no idea that he is on a train and one is waiting at the station? Just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I know it doesnt make sense but lets suppose it is Somehow.

Comment: Look. If they observe the train to have the same speed then they are on the same inertial reference frame, at least they can be thought of being on the same reference frame. Then there is no problem whatsoever!

Comment: Is this situation breaks the physics rules I mean same speed agreement

Comment: What no!! If you and I say that the car is travelling with 50km/h does it violate some physical law?? I'll let you think some time before I post anything any more. Think about what you have written and what answer have I given to them.

Comment: @ArmanÇam "agreeing on speed" is the same as agreeing to use the same frame of reference. If they use the same frame of reference then they compute the same kinetic energy. But that doesn't make that value of kinetic energy right in some overarching meaning. It is only right for the frame of reference the people in your scenario are using.

Comment: Ok I understand that they can agree on speed without break any rules.And they can agree on kinetic energy only when they think same speed

Comment: No need to apologize but briefly you can say yes that is the case.

Comment: @ArmanÇam BTW if my answer helped you in any way (I don't think it did much help but in any case), you can accept it by clicking the tick ✓ button.

Comment: yeah it helped me I dont know wheres the tick.I am asking again and again cause I wanna be sure this is some kind of my personality

Comment: [How does accepting an answer works?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I didnt understand your question and by the way my first language is not english so sometimes I can have problems to understand.